# Is there a function where I can print only one value from a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where i'd like to have the output return a specific value only.

If I had a pandas dataframe like below:

```
  Tick  Name   Contact
1. A     Tom    Phone
2. B     Simon  Email
3. C     Jim    Post
4. D     Sid    Phone
5. E     John   Email
```

How can I get the output of A without any other information.

I have used:

```
contractor = "Tom"
df.loc[df['Name']==contractor]
```

Which provides an output of:

```
  Tick  Name   Contact
1  A     Tom    Phone
```

I want the output to only show **A** nothing else. How could I do this ?

### INPUT:Tom

### OUTPUT: A

Comment: you can pass the desired series inside loc: `df.loc[df['Name']==contractor,'Tick'].iloc[0]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
df[df['Name']==contractor]["Tick"].values
```

As you tried yourself, `df[df['Name']==contractor]` filter only relevant rows. It returns a dataframe (a slice of it), so you use `["Tick"]` to select only one column from this dataframe. To get the values of cells you ca use `.values`.

You did not mentioned output you want in case there are more then 1 row matching. Right now this code all gives all values matching to your condition (name==contractor). If you want only one (aka the first) you can select it with `[0]` at the end: `df[df['Name']==contractor]["Tick"].values[0]`.